Would retaliation occur for attacking a slave in the afterlife even if the owner repents without freeing the slave?
It was mentioned in:
Al-Adab al-Mufrad - Al-Bukhari the following:

"181. 'Ammar ibn Yasir said, "None of you beats his slave unjustly without the slave receiving
retaliation from him on the Day of Rising."

Question: Would the retaliation for unjustly harming the slave occur on the slave owner on the day of judgment even if the slave owner repents to God? And is freeing the slave the only way to prevent the same thing happening to the slave owner on the day of judgement? Imam Bukhari also said there is no obligation to free the slave on earth
should the owner unjustly attack the him/her.
Thanks.

Repentance does not cause the rights of the people to be forgiven, unless they forgive it themselves. Indeed repentance requires that you e.g. allow them to take revenge or get compensated or to voluntarily forgive you.

I see, so the owner would get punished by God in the afterlife if not forgiven or retaliated in earth. But will the retaliation on the owner be equal to what was done on the slave or less?
